# MySQL Select from dropdown?

Tags: mysql

Want add simple function to my script.

I can select from in dropdown Yes, Or No with options show text in fron page or don't show.
This source frond end code, not sure how it works!

```
function showalert ()
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM filmdb ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
    while($fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            echo 'Show alert message!';
            echo '.$fetch['alertmsg'].';                        
        }

}
```

also in admin page with dropdown selection Don't Show = No and Show = Yes